# Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin (KMO) test returning strange results

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I'm running a KMO test in R to determine factorability of data using KMO(data_matrix) function. I read that this is a recommended step as part of structural equation modelling, to determine whether the data is suitable for factorising (part of EFA).

The output is an overall "MSA" value for the data set as well as individual ones for each attribute. Generally, if MSA above 0.7 it is considered that factorising is a suitable step for the data.

I expected to get a range of values for different attributes, but I have gotten 0.5 for every one. This leads me to think that either my data set is not suitable for the KMO test or large data sets in general are not suitable for factorizing. I have quite a large data set, of about 50K rows and 25 attributes.

Any insight on why it would return this value for every attribute? Could this be a legitimate result? How important is KMO test, and does anyone have advice for where to go from here if wanting to do SEM? Is it simply not a good option?

Comment: In the days when a factor analysis took days or weeks, you wanted to know if it was worth doing, before you did it. So you calculated the KMO - if that was low, you didn't bother. Nowadays it takes seconds, so you just run it and see.

Comment: Ok sure, it doesn't take long to run, but my understanding was that the results are not viable if the KMO test doesn't return msa values above at least 0.6. But you're saying this isn't the case, and KMO is redundant now?

Comment: I feel like KMO is redundant. Just do the factor analysis. (What would 'not viable' mean?)